# Scale or resize?

Tags: interface, transforms, scale

Just a newbie question, but while selecting the "scale" from Transform the "action" panel shows Resize instead. Is this a bug or something which is not fully clear for new users?

So far I haven't similar on other Transforms actions.

--
Pepi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,
   Scale actually means the size of your mesh. For instance (I am relating it to real life) you have a cube in real life then Suppose the length of the cube is 3 cm, width is 3 cm & height of that cube is 3 cm. It is the scale of the cube.

**Scale:**

on X-axis: 3 cm

on Y-axis: 3 cm

on Z-axis: 3 cm

If You increase the scale of that cube you are stretching it and actually you are increasing it's scale for example you stretched it & along X-axis through 2 cm. Then the scale of the cube will be

**Scale:**

on X-axis: 5 cm

on Y-axis: 3 cm

on Z-axis: 3 cm

**Definition of Scale:**

The relative extent of something; a thing's overall dimensions or magnitude; how big something is.

**Clear Answer:**

Its not a bug or something else. Its just name differently on the transform panel & action panel. The one thing I want add is that it is pretty clear to some new users but it can create confusion among some of the new users (really some of the new users most of new users will not find it a issue).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. It is just slightly confusing, as you also describing the scaling while the action panel have "resize" :)
It is very clear that both terms means the same, but using both terms at the same time makes it not so clear.

But now I know, thank you about that.

Comment: @Pepi Please Accept my answer if you see that question is right!